# Parsley Remote and Server Side Validation (can't get content from json object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, parsley.js

I am trying to validate if an email already exists in our database. I always get a 200 status code from the Ajax Request, but I get the body of the request that looks like this. Result =1 if that email does not exists and is available (the form should return true) and Result = 0 if that email already exists in the database (the from should return false and not validate). However I keep geting data undefined in the console. Seems like I don't know how to pass the json object to the function.

I'll buy a beer to anyone that can help me figure this out. Thank you.

**JSON RESPONSE**

```js
id: "1c29da8e-ca94-4ea4-a69f-f0af15f54bf5", redirectPage: "/public/actionStatus.jsp", errorText: "",…}
action: "/check.douserEmailAvailable"
data: {}
errorCode: ""
errorText: ""
id: "1c29da8e-ca94-4ea4-a69f-f0af15f54bf5"
redirectPage: "/public/actionStatus.jsp"
result: "1"
text1: ""
text2: ""
text3: ""
text4: ""
text5: ""
```

**JQUERY and HTML**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 window.Parsley.addAsyncValidator('mycustom', function (data) {
  if (data.result == 1) {
            console.log("does not exist");
            return true;
          } else {
            console.log("already exist");
            return false;
          }
   }, '/check.do?action=userEmailAvailable&ajax=1');
 
 
 $('#userReg').parsley();
});
```

```html
   <input type="email" name="userEmail1" data-parsley-remote data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST", "data": { "token": "value" } }' data-parsley-remote-validator='mycustom' id="userEmail1" value="" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument passed to your asynch validator is `xhr`, not `data`.

You can use `$.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)`, or `xhr.done(function(json){...})`, etc... to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, If anyone has issues in the future.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 window.Parsley.addAsyncValidator('emailvalidation', function (data) {
  var myResponseText = data.responseText;
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(myResponseText);  
  if (obj.result == 1) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
   }, '/check.do?action=userEmailAvailable&ajax=1');
 
 
 $('#userReg').parsley().on('form:success', function() {
  
  var formData = $("#userReg").serializeArray();
    var action = "<%=pdo.getRegistrationData().registrationType.toString()%>";
     
     $.post("/userRegistration.do?action="+ action +"&ajax=1", formData, 
       function(data) {
        window.location.href = data.redirectPage;
        });
 });
 
 
});
```